# calculating entry inputs in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Idle and tkinter.messagebox. I am trying to display the product of a calculation from entry inputs. I have been unable to figure out how to capture the user entries and then run the calculation and produce the result.

So, what I want the user to be able to input numbers, say 2, and 2. Then, I want the user to push a button. Next, the answer to 2+2 should appear in the blank entry label.

My question is how do I capture user inputs and use them in a calculation, then display the result?

```
mydict = {'good':0.7, 'average':0.5, 'optimal': 1, 'unacceptable': 0, 'major innovation': 1, 'minor innovation': 0.7, 'no innovation': 0.4, '1st lowest': 1, '2nd lowest': 0.7, '3rd lowest': 0.5, '4th lowest': 0.3}

# Widgets:
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
label1 = Label(master, text = 'Bid Number', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label2 = Label(master, text = 'Cost Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label3 = Label(master, text = 'Past Performance', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label8 = Label(master, text = 'Bid 1' , relief = 'groove', width = 12)
entry1 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
entry2 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label9 = Label(master, text = 'Bid Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)

def button_function():
    a = float( mydict[entry1.get()] ) * float( mydict[entry2.get()] )

button1 = Button(master, text = 'calculate', relief = 'groove', width = 12, command = button_function)
label16 = Frame(master, print(a))


#Geometry
label1.grid( row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10 )
label2.grid( row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10 )
label3.grid( row = 1, column = 3, padx = 10 )
label8.grid( row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10 )
entry1.grid( row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10 )
entry2.grid( row = 2, column = 3, padx = 10 )
label9.grid( row = 1, column = 8, padx = 10 )
label16.grid( row = 2, column = 8, padx = 10 )
button1.grid( row = 3, column = 4, columnspan = 2)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Having around 3 widgets should be enough to produce the demo code you'd need.

Comment: I tried to make it more minimal. Thanks!

Comment: This is much better but it produces errors, that the earlier code hasn't.

Comment: Have you read any documentation or searched this site? There are many, many questions related to getting data out of an Entry widget, and the method is documented.

Comment: Yes I have searched, I have not found anything helpful to this point. If there is something in particular you are referring to please let me know. I am doing my best, I have been coding for two weeks and have been teaching myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I needed to define show_answer and insert it into the blank, then command the button to show answer. Thanks for the help.

```
     mydict = {'good':0.7, 'average':0.5, 'optimal': 1, 'unacceptable': 0, 'major innovation': 1, 'minor innovation': 0.7, 'no innovation': 0.4, '1st lowest': 1, '2nd lowest': 0.7, '3rd lowest': 0.5, '4th lowest': 0.3}



 # Widgets:
    from tkinter import 
*from tkinter.messagebox import *


    master = Tk()
    label1 = Label(master, text = 'Bid Number', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
    label2 = Label(master, text = 'Cost Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
    label3 = Label(master, text = 'Past Performance', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
    label8 = Label(master, text = 'Bid 1' , relief = 'groove', width = 12)
    entry1 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
    entry2 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
    label9 = Label(master, text = 'Bid Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
    blank1 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 16)

    def button_function():
        float( mydict[entry1.get()] ) * float( mydict[entry2.get()] )

    def show_answer():
        Ans = float( mydict[entry1.get()] ) * float( mydict[entry2.get()] )
        blank1.insert(0, Ans)

    button1 = Button(master, text = 'calculate', relief = 'groove', width = 12, command =show_answer)


    #Geometry
    label1.grid( row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10 )
    label2.grid( row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10 )
    label3.grid( row = 1, column = 3, padx = 10 )
    label8.grid( row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10 )
    entry1.grid( row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10 )
    entry2.grid( row = 2, column = 3, padx = 10 )
    label9.grid( row = 1, column = 8, padx = 10 )
    blank1.grid( row = 2, column = 8, padx = 10 )
    button1.grid( row = 3, column = 4, columnspan = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this question would help *anyone* but you in its current state but I think what you're trying to achieve can be done by replacing:

```
def button_function():
    a = float( mydict[get(entry1)] ) * float( mydict[get(entry1)] ) * float( mydict[get(entry1)] ) *float( mydict[get(entry2)] ) * float( mydict[get(entry3)] ) *float( mydict[get(entry4)] ) * float( mydict[get(entry5)] ) * float( mydict[get(entry5)] ) * float( mydict[get(entry6)]) 
    ...
```

with:

```
def button_function():
    a = float( mydict[entry1.get()] ) * float( mydict[entry1.get()] )\
    * float( mydict[entry1.get()] ) *float( mydict[entry2.get()] )\
    * float( mydict[entry3.get()] ) *float( mydict[entry4.get()] )\
    * float( mydict[entry5.get()] ) * float( mydict[entry5.get()] )\
    * float( mydict[entry6.get()])
    ...
```

---

Additionally, add:

```
label16.grid()
button1.grid()
```

in order to display, not shown but obviously required to be shown widgets.

Comment: This helped, but I still can't click the calculate button to return the value in label16. To be clear, I want to type words into entry1-entry6, click calculate and then have the number appear in label16. Also, I think this will be helpful to others. Indeed, this would be helpful to anyone looking to calculate a geometric mean represented in an interface.